# How can I acces a device that uses Usbccgp driver

Tags: c#, c, usb, driver, data-transfer

In my project, ı need to write a program that can access an external soundcard and take discrete input sound data. The device uses isochronous data transfer and Usbccgp.sys driver. In that case, I can not use WinUsb and LibUsb functions. What should be my solution path in that situation? Writing a new driver to access the device or using another driver to communicate each interface of the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sound card probably already has drivers, assuming it is a real product made by a company who wants its users to actually be able to use it.  So you don't need to write drivers.

Just use the appropriate Windows sound API.  I'm not sure which one is the best, but here are some links to start off your research:

- [waveInOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-waveinopen)
- [About the Windows Core Audio APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/about-the-windows-core-audio-apis)

Comment: I have used `waveOutOpen` before to generate sound and the API was reasonable, and so I would try `waveInOpen` if I were you.